# Cannot find symbol: Thread.sleep (1000);

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to implement threads using the `Runnable` interface.

I have the following three classes:

FirstThread.java

```
public class FirstThread implements Runnable
{  

  //This method will be executed when this thread is executed  
  public void run()    
  {                

    //Looping from 1 to 10 to display numbers from 1 to 10     
    for ( int i=1; i<=10; i++)      
    {          
        //Displaying the numbers from this thread          
        System.out.println( "Messag from First Thread : " +i);                     

       /*taking a delay of one second before displaying next number              
        *            
        * "Thread.sleep(1000);" - when this statement is executed,           
        * this thread will sleep for 1000 milliseconds (1 second)           
        * before executing the next statement.           
        *            
        * Since we are making this thread to sleep for one second,           
        * we need to handle "InterruptedException". Our thread           
        * may throw this exception if it is interrupted while it             
        * is sleeping.           
        *            
        */         
        try            
        {              
           Thread.sleep (1000);            
        }          
        catch (InterruptedException interruptedException)          
        {              
           /*Interrupted exception will be thrown when a sleeping or waiting
            *thread is interrupted.                  
            */             
            System.out.println( "First Thread is interrupted when it is sleeping" +interruptedException);          
        }  
    }  
  }
}
```

SecondThread.java:

```
public class SecondThread implements Runnable
{  

   //This method will be executed when this thread is executed 
   public void run()   
   {           

      //Looping from 1 to 10 to display numbers from 1 to 10       
      for ( int i=1; i<=10; i++)        
      {            
         System.out.println( "Messag from Second Thread : " +i);                       

        /*taking a delay of one second before displaying next number             
         *           
         * "Thread.sleep(1000);" - when this statement is executed,              
         * this thread will sleep for 1000 milliseconds (1 second)           
         * before executing the next statement.              
         *          
         * Since we are making this thread to sleep for one second,              
         * we need to handle "InterruptedException". Our thread              
         * may throw this exception if it is interrupted while it            
         * is sleeping.              
         */            
         try           
         {             
             Thread.sleep(1000);           
         }         
         catch (InterruptedException interruptedException)         
         {             
            /*Interrupted exception will be thrown when a sleeping or waiting                
             * thread is interrupted.                
             */                
             System.out.println( "Second Thread is interrupted when it is sleeping" +interruptedException);            
         }     
      }    
    } 
}
```

ThreadDemo.java:

```
public class ThreadDemo
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
        //Creating an object of the first thread
        FirstThread   firstThread = new FirstThread();

        //Creating an object of the Second thread
        SecondThread   secondThread = new SecondThread();

        //Starting the first thread
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(firstThread);
        thread1.start();

        //Starting the second thread
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(secondThread);
        thread2.start();
     }
}
```

On compiling above programs, I got the following errors:

FirstThread

```
shahjahan@shahjahan-AOD270:~/Documents/java$ javac FirstThread.java 
FirstThread.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
           Thread.sleep (1000);            
                 ^
  symbol:   method sleep(int)
  location: class Thread
1 error
```

SecondThread:

```
    shahjahan@shahjahan-AOD270:~/Documents/java$ javac SecondThread.java 
    SecondThread.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
                 Thread.sleep(1000);           
                       ^
      symbol:   method sleep(int)
      location: class Thread
    1 error
```

ThreadDemo:

```
shahjahan@shahjahan-AOD270:~/Documents/java$ javac ThreadDemo.java 
ThreadDemo.java:12: error: constructor Thread in class Thread cannot be applied to given types;
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(firstThread);
                         ^
  required: no arguments
  found: FirstThread
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
ThreadDemo.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        thread1.start();
               ^
  symbol:   method start()
  location: variable thread1 of type Thread
ThreadDemo.java:16: error: constructor Thread in class Thread cannot be applied to given types;
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(secondThread);
                         ^
  required: no arguments
  found: SecondThread
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
ThreadDemo.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        thread2.start();
               ^
  symbol:   method start()
  location: variable thread2 of type Thread
./FirstThread.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
           Thread.sleep (1000);            
                 ^
  symbol:   method sleep(int)
  location: class Thread
./SecondThread.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
             Thread.sleep(1000);           
                   ^
  symbol:   method sleep(int)
  location: class Thread
6 errors
```

I am novice in java. Why thread.sleep is not working. Does thread implementation depends on the machine on which it is compiled?

Comment: You need to show us all your 'import' statements too, not just the class body. My expectation is that you are importing some other `Thread` class.

Comment: Pretty sure you have your own `Thread` class defined somewhere

Comment: @learner, check the very first error -- that's your problem.  Here's a hint: line 12 of ThreadDemo.java.

Comment: java.lang.Thread should be your import.

Comment: you dont need to import classes from java.lang

Comment: @bedwyr I have defined a Thread class in the same directory. Now it works fine..

Comment: Remember that all the public and package-private classes in the same package are automatically visible to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you are importing some class with the name `Thread`, that is not `java.lang.Thread`, or there is a class called `Thread` in your current code directory that is 'polluting' the imports for your class.

Remove/rename any classes called 'Thread' in your folder, and remove any imports for a class called `Thread`

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with your code, i tested it and it's working fine.

You probably have a conflicting Thread class, if there are any classes called Thread in your project remove or rename them, and try again.

Comment: yes you are right. How can I know whether I have a thread class defined or not?

Comment: look at your import statements and you will see which "Thread" it is using

Comment: @learner - if you are using an IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ, etc.) it is easy, for example, in Eclipse put the cursor on the word 'Thread', and press `f3`

Comment: You arent importing any in your code, so I'm guessing you are using some messed up library, or you have a Thread.java file in the same src directory as your java files

Comment: Actually I think it did answer the question since it wasn't an import problem, and proved that there is no problems with his coding. 
A conflicting Thread.java seemed the most logical explanation. There is an accepted answer now anyway so it doesn't really matter anymore, but how did I not answer the question?